# Android Receiver randomly becomes disabled

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an application with a Receiver defined in the `AndroidManifest.xml` and it is, seemingly, randomly becoming disabled which causes the app to force close until the app is re-installed.  App might work fine for a day, a week or a month before this happens.

Relevant output from `adb shell dumpsys`:

```
  Package [com.example.helloworld.debug] (34181cc):
    userId=10196 gids=[3003, 1028, 1015, 3002, 3001]
    pkg=Package{388362dc com.example.helloworld.debug}
    codePath=/data/app/com.example.helloworld.debug-1
    resourcePath=/data/app/com.example.helloworld.debug-1
    legacyNativeLibraryDir=/data/app/com.example.helloworld.debug-1/lib
    primaryCpuAbi=null
    secondaryCpuAbi=null
    versionCode=1 targetSdk=22
    versionName=1.0d
    splits=[base]
    applicationInfo=ApplicationInfo{2a384fe5 com.example.helloworld.debug}
    flags=[ DEBUGGABLE HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA VM_SAFE_MODE ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    dataDir=/data/data/com.example.helloworld.debug
    supportsScreens=[small, medium, large, xlarge, resizeable, anyDensity]
    timeStamp=2015-06-02 13:42:27
    firstInstallTime=2015-06-02 13:42:27
    lastUpdateTime=2015-06-02 13:42:27
    signatures=PackageSignatures{126ffaba [1dee9d6b]}
    permissionsFixed=true haveGids=true installStatus=1
    pkgFlags=[ DEBUGGABLE HAS_CODE ALLOW_CLEAR_USER_DATA VM_SAFE_MODE ALLOW_BACKUP ]
    User 0:  installed=true hidden=false stopped=false notLaunched=false enabled=0
      disabledComponents:
      com.et.sdk.ETLocationReceiver
    grantedPermissions:
      com.example.helloworld.debug.permission.C2D_MESSAGE
      com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
      android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
      android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED
      android.permission.BLUETOOTH
      android.permission.INTERNET
      android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
      android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
      android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
      android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
      android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD
      android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS
      android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
      android.permission.VIBRATE
      android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
      android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
```

Relevant portion of the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<!-- ETLocationReceiver and Service -->
<receiver android:name="com.et.sdk.ETLocationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Full source can be found on GitHub https://github.com/androidfu/EtPushHelloWorld

Comment: You're sure that you're not force-stopping this app, or disabling this receiver through `PackageManager`?

Comment: I was using the app successfully for the past 2 days.  At some point while driving last night it started Force Closing and now it will not launch until I re-install.  The SDK that contains that ETLocationReceiver also has an ETPushReceiver.  The ETPushReceiver is verified successfully before the ETLocationReceiver is check and the ETLocationReceiver check is failing (because it's been disabled.)

Comment: @CommonsWare upon further review: you are right! When the battery_low receiver was fired we disabled our Location Receiver, but when the battery_okay receiver kicked off we check the manifest for the appropriate receiver and it was disabled so the list was empty.

Comment: Whew. You had me scared for a bit there. Glad it's working for you!

Comment: Phrase that 1st statement in the form of an answer and I'll give you the check-mark/upvote @CommonsWare ;)  Much appreciated.

Comment: IMHO, the SO community would be better served if you expanded your "upon further review" comment as an answer, given the way that your question is constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further review it turns out that a BATTERY_LOW condition was disabling the LocationReceiver.  Thank you for the tip @CommonsWare which made me keep digging.